# Zipcode search, but users have radius they serve

Tags: mysql, search, zipcode

We have a site where users can search for service providers (customers looking for service providers).  The site currently has a MySQL zipcode search doing a classic radius around the lat/long point of the searched zipcode, matching all zipcodes whose lat/long are within the radius circle of the searched zipcode. Then matching all service providers which put their address in one of the matching zipcodes.

Say a user is searching for service providers within 25 miles. Service providers that are 50 miles would normally not show up in this search. However, we want to give service providers the option to enter a radius for which they server. Even if they are 50 miles away, they may have a service radius of 100 miles - so this user would appear in the 25 mile radius search.

Basically drawing a radius circle around two points and seeing if they intersect.

Any ideas? I have no idea where to start here or if something like this is possible or even advisable.

Our fallback will be to allow service providers to enter zipcodes they serve but this is a bit more cumbersome for service providers.

Comment: Perhaps I've misunderstood but aren't you trying to get the results of an inner join? And then Union them with the '25 mile' results? Are you wanting to achieve this client side or server side?

Comment: I don't know if what I want is the results of an inner join + union. Sounds like maybe I do? I want to do this server side, using MySQL and PHP.

Comment: Sounds like you just need to find results where the business is within the user's radius, or the user is within the business' radius.  In this case, checking both in the same sql statement and returning the result if either matches would be what you should do.  You already have half of that done with the user's radius.  You don't really need to see if the circles intersect.  Only to see if one of either location's circle contains the others zip code.

Comment: You might need to post a schema or skeleton code from your 'MySQL zipcode search' with the 'radius around the lat/long' point. Otherwise, at best you'll get some pseudo code...

Comment: Pseudo code is fine with me, this is more of a conceptual question. I think I am going to go with when the service provider saves their profile, do a zipcode search at that time and grab all the zipcodes they serve and save to their profile. Then when the user searches it will see if it matches any of the zipcodes the service provider is a part of. With thousands and thousands of profiles, I want to keep the front end search query as minimal as possible so it does not take forever to work.

Comment: I like James idea, but not quite sure how to do it. The site uses WordPress so all users have attributes stored as meta data in a separate table. If the user has 100 mile service radius - how do I do a single SQL statement that does the current zipcode search but then also does the reverse and gets every single service providers radius and does a distance calculation from the service provider to the user to see if they are within that radius? Also, wouldn't this mean MySQL has to run this on every single service provider in the database which seems like it would take forever.